# timezone in microsoft sharepoint api is inccorect

Tags: rest, sharepoint

My local time zone is GMT+8, and my time is 15:xx GMT+8, but when I update the list item in SharePoint, it returns the modified time is 07:xx GMT-8

Make both of them to GMT:

- Mine is 07:xx GMT
- Sharepoint returns 15:xx GMT

Any idea on fixing it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsmwB.png]

Comment: screenshot in postman attached

Comment: It looks like you are querying sharepoint online or something. If it the case then you can follow this instruction to change Sp regional setting
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-regional-settings-for-a-site-e9e189c7-16e3-45d3-a090-770be6e83c1a

Comment: Ah, I think it's nothing to the region, I calculate them to GMT, they are different, I thought they should be the same.